# A Timetable that show ongoing Activities( eg Classes, Testes ) within a Week

Tags: android, android-layout

How to display schedule like (Classes, Testes and so on) for college App Using a Timetable, for eg like this

[image: Timetable]

I was thinking of extending FrameLayout and customize it in some way, Any help?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `TableLayout` to design the desired view. According to documentation `TableLayout` is **[A layout that arranges its children into rows and columns.](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TableLayout)** This I think is the best suit for you` as you have given number of rows and columns.

Here is an example of `TableLayout` you can extend to fit your needs:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_marginTop="100dp"
android:paddingLeft="10dp"
android:paddingRight="10dp" >
<TableRow android:background="#0079D6" android:padding="5dp">
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="title 1" />
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="title 2" />
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="title 3" />
</TableRow>
<TableRow android:background="#DAE8FC" android:padding="5dp">
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="1" />
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="Suresh Dasari" />
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="Hyderabad" />
</TableRow>
<TableRow android:background="#DAE8FC" android:padding="5dp">
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="2" />
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="Rohini Alavala" />
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="Guntur" />
</TableRow>
<TableRow android:background="#DAE8FC" android:padding="5dp">
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="3" />
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="Trishika Dasari" />
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="Guntur" />
</TableRow>
```